# Are there people who are able to understand the architecture of a rig of cartoon characters form Sprite Fright?

Tags: rigging

Are there people who are able to understand the architecture of a rig of cartoon characters form Sprite Fright blender movie which are available at Blender Studio?

Except for those who created this rig

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are.  They fall into (at least) three categories:

1. The people at Blender Studio who created the rigs.
2. The people in or out of Blender Studio who are [Blender Cloud](https://studio.blender.org/) (now Blender Studio) subscribers and have taken the time to watch the excellent videos and read the excellent blog posts by the Blender Studio Team, especially the [*"Learn to rig like the Blender Studio"*](https://studio.blender.org/blog/learn-to-rig-like-the-blender-studio/) blog post -- which I believe is only available to subscribers.
3. People who like to reverse engineer rigging and have done so with these rigs.